# Why is the U.S. version of Bing better than the versions for other languages?

Tags: web, search-engines, bing, localization, i18n

I'm pretty sure that most of you noticed the difference in the [**Microsoft search engine Bing**](http://www.bing.com/) when switching between languages on the top right corner! Actually the ones other than the United States are so basic and have no home page "add-ons" that we can see on the United States one, like hovering over an image and getting more information about the background, the quick list at the left and a lot of others.

What are the secrets behind that? And why they don't make all the domains (if we can say so) with the same functions with different UI language?

Comment: Good lord. What a mess.

Comment: i18n?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's mainly a translation issue. Since the service is still considered beta, there is probably lots of experimentation and changes on short notice. Having to translate everything involved to 30 different languages before making any change would slow down that kind of development drastically.

I'm pretty sure Microsoft will consider rolling out all features to all localized versions a top priority once things have settled down - they usually spend a lot of effort on localization, and it has paid off nicely for them: in some of the more difficult locales (such as Israel, from what I hear), their monopoly status is even more extreme than elsewhere.